# How to Remove Data from WC API Endpoint Request?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm shipping off order data to a 3rd party piece of fulfillment software. They integrate by default with the WooCommerce REST API. However some recent changes to my site and order data have added additional order meta. Now when grabbing the same amount of orders as it always has the request times out with a 504. The request is now unreasonably large, to fix this I've decided to optimize by reducing the irrelevant and unnecessary data produced by the request. Also I have to be able to process 100 at a time I cannot reduce the filter limit, its automatically set by the 3rd party application.

### Endpoint in Question

```
wc-api/v2/orders?status=processing&page=1&filter%5Blimit%5D=100
```

This endpoint grabs the first 100 orders in processing and displays them as a piece of JSON.

### Things to Remove

1. customer_user_agent
2. avatar_url
3. cogs_cost
4. cogs_total_cost

### Example Response

```
{
   "orders":[
      {
         "id":137314,
         "order_number":"137314",
         "created_at":"2019-09-18T18:37:06Z",
         "updated_at":"2019-09-18T18:37:07Z",
         "completed_at":"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
         "status":"processing",
         "currency":"USD",
         "total":"49.50",
         "subtotal":"55.00",
         "total_line_items_quantity":1,
         "total_tax":"0.00",
         "total_shipping":"0.00",
         "cart_tax":"0.00",
         "shipping_tax":"0.00",
         "total_discount":"0.00",
         "shipping_methods":"Free shipping",
         "payment_details":{
            "method_id":"nmipay",
            "method_title":"Pay with Credit Card",
            "paid":true
         },
         "billing_address":{
            "first_name":"XXX",
            "last_name":"XXXX",
            "company":"",
            "address_1":"XXXX",
            "address_2":"",
            "city":"XXXX",
            "state":"XX",
            "postcode":"XXXXX",
            "country":"US",
            "email":"XXXXXX",
            "phone":"XXXX"
         },
         "shipping_address":{
            "first_name":"XXX",
            "last_name":"XX",
            "company":"",
            "address_1":"XXXXX",
            "address_2":"",
            "city":"XXX",
            "state":"XXX",
            "postcode":"XXX",
            "country":"XXXX"
         },
         "note":"",
         "customer_ip":"98.216.25.236",
         "customer_user_agent":"mozilla\/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 12_4_1 like mac os x) applewebkit\/605.1.15 (khtml, like gecko) version\/12.1.2 mobile\/15e148 safari\/604.1",
         "customer_id":127116,
         "view_order_url":"XXXXX",
         "line_items":[
            {
               "id":198261,
               "subtotal":"55.00",
               "subtotal_tax":"0.00",
               "total":"55.00",
               "total_tax":"0.00",
               "price":"55.00",
               "quantity":1,
               "tax_class":"",
               "name":"Core Hoodie - Black, Large",
               "product_id":351,
               "sku":"ss-hoodie-core-zip-blk-lg",
               "meta":[

               ],
               "bundled_by":"",
               "bundled_item_title":"",
               "bundled_items":[

               ],
               "cogs_cost":"23.15",
               "cogs_total_cost":"23.15"
            }
         ],
         "shipping_lines":[
            {
               "id":198263,
               "method_id":"free_shipping",
               "method_title":"Free shipping",
               "total":"0.00"
            }
         ],
         "tax_lines":[

         ],
         "fee_lines":[
            {
               "id":198262,
               "title":"VIP Discount",
               "tax_class":"0",
               "total":"-5.50",
               "total_tax":"0.00"
            }
         ],
         "coupon_lines":[

         ],
         "cogs_total_cost":"23.15"
      }
   ]
}
```

#### This is the furthest i've gotten

I found the following hooks but cannot get anything to trigger.

```
woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object
woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order
```

```
function remove_user_agent_from_rest_api( $response, $object, $request ) {
    unset($response->data['customer_user_agent']);
    return $response;
}

function test_rest_api() {
add_filter( "woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_shop_order", "remove_user_agent_from_rest_api", 10, 2 );
add_filter( "woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_shop_order_object", "remove_user_agent_from_rest_api", 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'test_rest_api', 0 );
```

### Is this a performance tuning issue?

Here is a sample trace from new relic & a sample from my NGINX Error Log. What could I tune to keep the server open long enough to process this request.

[image]

```
2019/10/02 10:59:25 [error] 10270#10270: *5 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX, server: X.net, request: "GET /?km_source=blog HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "X.net", referrer: "https://www.X.net/"
2019/10/02 11:00:42 [error] 10270#10270: *34 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX, server: XXX.net, request: "GET /wc-api/v2/orders?status=processing&page=10&filter%5Blimit%5D=100&consumer_key=ck_XXX&consumer_secret=cs_XXX HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "X.net"
2019/10/02 11:07:53 [error] 13021#13021: *62 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX, server: XXX.net, request: "GET /wc-api/v2/orders?status=processing&page=1&filter%5Blimit%5D=100&consumer_key=ck_XXX&consumer_secret=cs_XXX HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "X.net"
2019/10/02 11:13:45 [error] 15270#15270: *66 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX, server: XXX.net, request: "GET /wc-api/v2/orders?status=processing&page=1&filter%5Blimit%5D=100&consumer_key=ck_XXX&consumer_secret=cs_XXX HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "XXX.net"
2019/10/02 11:15:44 [error] 16010#16010: *79 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX, server: X.net, request: "GET /wc-api/v2/orders?status=processing&page=1&filter%5Blimit%5D=100&consumer_key=ck_XXX&consumer_secret=cs_XXX HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "X.net"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I'd notice it that your filters are only passing 2 variables, when they should be passing 3.

`add_filter( "woocommerce_rest_pre_insert_shop_order", "remove_user_agent_from_rest_api", 10, 3 );`

Should do it.